# TemplateDoesNotExist - Django Error

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django Rest Framework. and I keep getting an error

```
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value: rest_framework/api.html
```

I dont know how I'm going wrong. This is the first time I'm trying out hands on REST Framework.
This is code.

**views.py**

```
import socket, json
from modules.data.models import *
from modules.utils import *
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from modules.actions.serializers import ActionSerializer


@api_view(['POST'])
@check_field_exists_wrapper("installation")
def api_actions(request, format = None):

    action_type = request.POST['action_type']
    if action_type == "Shutdown" : 
        send_message = '1'
        print "Shutting Down the system..."
    elif action_type == "Enable" : 
        send_message = '1'
        print "Enabling the system..."
    elif action_type == "Disable" : 
        send_message = '1'
        print "Disabling the system..."
    elif action_type == "Restart" : 
        send_message = '1'
        print "Restarting the system..."

    if action_type in ["Shutdown", "Enable", "Disable"] : PORT = 6000
    else : PORT = 6100

    controllers_list = Controller.objects.filter(installation_id = kwargs['installation_id'])

    for controller_obj in controllers_list:
        ip = controller_obj.ip
        try:
            s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            s.connect((ip, PORT))
            s.send(send_message)
            s.close()
        except Exception as e:
            print("Exception when sending " + action_type +" command: "+str(e))

    return Response(status = status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

**models.py**

```
class Controller(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key = True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255, unique = True)
    ip = models.CharField(max_length = 255, unique = True)
    installation_id = models.ForeignKey('Installation')
```

**serializers.py**

from django.forms import widgets
from rest_framework import serializers
from modules.data.models import *

```
class ActionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Controller
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'ip', 'installation_id')
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns

urlpatterns = patterns('modules.actions.views',
    url(r'^$','api_actions',name='api_actions'),
)
```

Comment: Do you have "rest_framework" listed in your settings.py INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: Noobest mistake. Thanks for it.

Comment: I've another doubt. How do I get a form in this so that I post some data in the form, hit the DB with those values and get the result? `How do I get the form?`

Comment: @ScottWoodall please post the answer, and get some points!

Answer (score 300, accepted):

Make sure you have `rest_framework` listed in your `settings.py` `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: Could also result from not registering a dependency of DRF. In my case I had to add `'django_hstore',` to `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Answer (score 6):

Please note that the DRF attempts to return data in the same format that was requested. From your browser, this is most likely HTML. To specify an alternative response, use the `?format=` parameter. For example: `?format=json`.

The `TemplateDoesNotExist` error occurs most commonly when you are visiting an API endpoint in your browser and you do *not* have the `rest_framework` included in your list of installed apps, as described by other respondents.

If you do not have DRF included in your list of apps, but don't want to use the HTML Admin DRF page, try using an alternative format to 'side-step' this error message.

More info from the docs here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/browsable-api/#formats

Answer (score 5):

For me, `rest_framework/api.html` was actually missing on the filesystem due to a corrupt installation or some other unknown reason. Reinstalling `djangorestframework` fixed the problem:

```
$ pip install --upgrade djangorestframework
```

Comment: Same thing happened to me. Note that command will upgrade to a maybe incompatible version (even if your setup.py and/or requirements.txt says otherwise). You can try pip uninstall/install or specify the exact version.

Answer (score 4):

Not your case, but also possible reason is customized `loaders` for `Django`. For example, if you have in settings (since `Django 1.8`):

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    ...
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages'
        ],
        'loaders': [
            'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
        ],
        ...
    }
}]
```

Django will not try to look at applications folders with templates, because you should explicitly add `django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader` into `loaders` for that.

Notice, that by default `django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader` included into `loaders`.

Comment: WARNINGS:
?: (1_8.W001) The standalone TEMPLATE_* settings were deprecated in Django 1.8 and the TEMPLATES dictionary takes precedence. You must put the values of the following settings into your default TEMPLATES dict: TEMPLATE_DEBUG.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error message. In my case, it was due to setting the backend to Jinja2. In my settings file:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2',
...
```

Changing this back to the default fixed the problem:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
...
```

Still not sure if there is a way to use the Jinja2 backend with rest_framework.

Answer (score 0):

We can get the error even if we missed adding the 'rest_framework' in the installed apps.
So please check that too if you are facing the error.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. The question is about 8 years old and already has an accepted answer.